# C# HttpListener treats all URLs as not valid

Tags: c#, .net, http, exception, httplistener

Encountered a very strange problem with C# HttpListener. After trying to add a new prefix to it, it started treating every URL as invalid - including localhost, which, looking at other questions I've looked through, works every time.

Code I'm using is nothing complicated, but, still, here it is

```
using HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost/");
listener.Start();
```

Specifically, error I'm getting is the following:
`System.Net.HttpListenerException (1214): The format of the specified network name is not valid`

Comment: Can you give the output of the cmd command `netsh http show urlacl | findstr "Reserved"` Are there any that are sitting on `http://*:80/`

Comment: @Charlieface it's output is completely empty

Comment: I normally use weak wildcard: listener.Prefixes.Add(string.Format("http://*:{0}/{1}", portData.PortHttp, endpoint)); It requires to be started as administrator